# JSON parser that allows newlines in strings?

Tags: json

I have some Python scripts that take in a set of parameters from a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "args": {
         "arg1": "Short Argument",
         "arg2": "Short Argument",
    },
    "queries": [
         {
             "name": "Query 1",
             "query": "SELECT key,\n    value1,\n    value2,\n ... FROM ..."
         }
    ]
}
```

I expect the query tag to contain rather long SQL queries, and the file above can be parsed back into Python with little to no difficulty.

However, I do need to change the SQL query from time to time as requirements change, and editing it when it is in the above format is irritating at best. I would hope for something that looks more like the following:

```
{
    "args": {
         "arg1": "Short Argument",
         "arg2": "Short Argument",
    },
    "queries": [
         {
             "name": "Query 1",
             "query": "
                 SELECT key,
                     value1,
                     value2,
                     ... 
                  FROM ..."
         }
    ]
}
```

I realize that this isn't legal syntax for a JSON file, but I was wondering if there were any existing tools that I could use to convert something like above into valid JSON. I'd rather keep my SQL embedded within the JSON so I don't have to keep track of a few hundred files.

Comment: You could try JSON5 https://pypi.org/project/json5/